# How do you know it's the first run of a Bitbucket pipeline for a new branch?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

How do I know it's the first run of a pipeline for a new branch?

On systems like Jenkins there is a `BUILD_NUMBER` environment variable. On the first run the variable will be `1`.

I have specific logic that should only be executed if it's the first build of a new feature branch.

Bitbucket's "build numbers" are always unique though: https://bitbucket.org/blog/bitbucket-pipelines-can-count-builds-numbered

Does Bitbucket provide a way to know if it's the first run of a build? Or is there some environment variable that tracks the current run number?

Comment: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/ there is no such env variable baseline

Comment: I don't think there is any way to check that. I don't know what are you trying to achieve but I think you should try to subscribe to create branch / create PR events instead (without bitbucket-pipelines)

Comment: I was wondering if it could be possible with git calls, but that would also not work. A user could make many local commits before creating the branch locally and first pushing to remote. So I can't just check if the `BITBUCKET_COMMIT` was the first commit made to a new branch.

Comment: Perhaps you could make bb APIs calls from inside a pipeline and list all the builds of a branch? Is that possible? Then you could just check the number of builds triggered for a branch right?